# Loading class from bin folder

Tags: java, eclipse, byte, classloader, bin

I would like to use .class file from bin folder in my code - convert it to bytes, but have no idea how to get to it. I have bin/example.class and I need to load it and check how many bytes does my class have.

I found something like:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader{ 

      public MyClassLoader(){ 
            super(MyClassLoader.class.getClassLoader()); 
      } 
}
```

But it doesn't seem to help, it must be some extremely easy way to do this. It looks really easy and whole internet try to push me into writing thousand lines of classLoader Code.

EDIT: My java file is compiled programatically and .class file is created programatically, so I can't just refer to it's name, it's also somewhere else in workspace.

Some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the bin folder to your class path!

To get the number of bytes, get the resource URL, convert to a File object and query the size.

Example:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Example {

    public static final String NAME = Example.class.getSimpleName() + ".class";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        URL url = Example.class.getResource(NAME);
        long size = new File(url.toURI().getPath()).length();
        System.out.printf("The size of file '%s' is %d bytes\n", NAME, size);
    }

}
```

Will output:

The size of file 'Example.class' is 1461 bytes

Comment: You mean build path, right? I got error message: "Source folder 'src' in project 'Example' cannot output to distinct source folder 'bin'"

Comment: I assume you are using Eclipse? Then the bin folder is already on your class path if you enable "create separate folders for sources and class files" during project creation. I will add example code to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need to add - my java file is compiled programmatically and .class file is created programmatically, so I can't refer to it writing code - because it doesn't exist yet...

Comment: In that case you have to use the File object with a path as String. You must know where to find it :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after all operation on f.e. file object I have to send this class to device with JVM. And i have no idea how to convert from the File to class.. Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader { 

    protected synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
        throws ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
            return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            // TODO: test, if you can load the class with 
            // the given name. if not, rethrow the exception!

            byte[] b = loadClassData(name);
            return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
        }

    }

    private byte[] loadClassData(String name) {
        // TODO: read contents of your file to byte array
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you specify how to convert my not existing class to byte array? Some example of line "// TODO: read contents of your file to byte array" please...

Comment: Open your file using a fileInputStream, and read that into a byte array.